# Some conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The NBA championship is won by the first team that wins 4 games in a best of seven series. Given two evenly matched teams, what is the probability that the team that has won three of the first four games will win the championship?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the other team wins all 3 remaining games is $1-$ the probability you are looking for.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: In order to win, the other team has to win all 3 remaining games. I don't think I can clarify much more.